# character casing for abbreviations in dotnet

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

Have you ever wondered why MS doesn't write abbreviations in all upper case? Like Guid, BmpBitmapEncoder, System.Net.Mime, HttpWebRequest, XmlDocument, etc., instead of GUID, BMPBitmapEncoder, System.Net.MIME, HTTPWebRequest, XMLDocument. I suspect it's for better readability, but in my opinion, it's worse, and maybe even a bit incorrect. Is there an MS document that explains why they decided to do it like this? I'm sure it's intentional, but here's a bonus question, find a name in the BCL which contains an all upper case abbreviation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule they use is that two-character acronyms are left uppercase: `IOException`

While longer acronyms are treated as words and use initial cap.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx:

> The following guidelines specify the proper casing for short and long acronyms. The identifier casing rules take precedence over acronym casing rules.
>
> **Do capitalize both characters of two-character acronyms, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.**
>
> A property named `DBRate` is an example of a short acronym (DB) used as the first word of a Pascal-cased identifier. A parameter named `ioChannel` is an example of a short acronym (IO) used as the first word of a camel-cased identifier.
>
> **Do capitalize only the first character of acronyms with three or more characters, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.**
>
> A class named `XmlWriter` is an example of a long acronym used as the first word of a Pascal-cased identifier. A parameter named `htmlReader` is an example of a long acronym used as the first word of a camel-cased identifier.
>
> **Do not capitalize any of the characters of any acronyms, whatever their length, at the beginning of a camel-cased identifier.**
>
> A parameter named `xmlStream` is an example of a long acronym (xml) used as the first word of a camel-cased identifier. A parameter named `dbServerName` is an example of a short acronym (db) used as the first word of a camel-cased identifier.

Comment: This is one of the very few naming conventions used in .NET that I actually like, and that makes sense.

Comment: Silly me, I was looking for the word character casing but not capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a reference to *why* it is so (but I expect readability was the concern). However, it is stated in the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx), that abbreviations with more than 2 letters should be PascalCased.

> "Do capitalize only the first character
>   of acronyms with three or more
>   characters, except the first word of a
>   camel-cased identifier."